# firefox css animation rotate issue

Tags: css, firefox, animation, rotation

i want a css rotation where i have a back and a front page wich should rotate multiple times on page load.

everything works fine in chrome (webkit), but on firefox front page is turned to the wrong side when the half of the animation is reached. (i'm not paying attention on other browsers atm)

can anyone give me a hint how to fix it to work with both browsers?

here is the codepen with a stripped down example: http://codepen.io/emrox/pen/wBGqgp

and this is some of the code for firefox:

```css
.front,
.back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes intro-turn-animation-front {
    0% { transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg); }
    50% { transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg) perspective(400px); }
    100% { transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 1deg); }
}

@keyframes intro-turn-animation-back {
    0% { transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg); }
    50% { transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg) perspective(400px); }
    100% { transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -179deg); }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="front"></div>
        <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying `perspective` inside `@keyframes`. The correct way is to apply it on the parent element not on the elements that you want the perspective effect on. That was causing the issue.

So, apply the `perspective` on `.container`.

### [codepen](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/raezPa)

```css
.front,
.back {
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-perspective: 400px;
  perspective: 400px;
}
.front {
  background-color: red;
}
.back {
  background-color: blue;
}
@-webkit-keyframes intro-turn-animation-front {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 1deg);
  }
}
@keyframes intro-turn-animation-front {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 360deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 1deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes intro-turn-animation-back {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -180deg);
  }
}
@keyframes intro-turn-animation-back {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -179deg);
  }
}
.front {
  -webkit-animation: intro-turn-animation-front 2s ease-in-out 5 normal;
  animation: intro-turn-animation-front 2s ease-in-out 5 normal;
}
.back {
  -webkit-animation: intro-turn-animation-back 2s ease-in-out 5 normal;
  animation: intro-turn-animation-back 2s ease-in-out 5 normal;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```